# Metodo recursivo que muestre los N primeros numeros naturales del 1 al N

Tags: java

Tengo un metodo recursivo para que muestre los N primeros numeros naturales del 1 al N por ejemplo 11, me da como resultado 11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,111, porque al ultimo me esta dando 111? donde esta el problema?

```
public class JavaApplication39 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 11;
        int resultado = numNatural(n);
        System.out.println(resultado);

    }


    public static int numNatural(int n){
    if(n==1){
      System.out.print(n);
      return n;
    }else {
      System.out.print(n+",");
        return 1+numNatural(n-1);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que el último este dando 111, lo que pasa es que se imprime 11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 e inmediatamente después se imprime 11 y por eso parece que se imprime 111 al final.

Soluciónalo quitando el `System.out.println(resultado);` que está dentro del método main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 11;
    numNatural(n);
}
```

O etiquétalo con algo para diferenciarlo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 11;
    int resultado = numNatural(n);
    System.out.println("\nResultado: " + resultado);
}
```